# How to show android splash screen in landscape mode?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, splash-screen

I am working on an android app and would like to show a splash screen in landscape mode when the system loads the app.

I made a small test app to reproduce the problem and saw that it actually works in portrait mode, but when I add this line `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` to my manifest it suddenly doesn't work anymore. It doesn't show any splash screen as if the property `windowPreviewDisabled` was set to true.
Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

My manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"  android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

style xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

launch screen xml (which is inside `layout-land` folder):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/logo2"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);`
in your activity after the setContentView method.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. I basically start in portrait mode and then switch to landscape mode in `onCreate`. Still not sure though why it doesn't work in landscape mode.

Comment: Strange that this doesn't work. Did you tried to set your layout programmatically? Like so: 
 `if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            createHorizontalalLayout();            
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            createVerticalLayout();             
        }`